# Regex remove pattern from match

Tags: regex, date

Tried to find answer but didn't make it.

So, let's say I have a string

```
12/01/2014 22:13 1,600/1,800 *or*
12/01/2014 22:13 100/200 *or*
12/01/2014 22:13 1,600/1,800 A *or*
12/01/2014 22:13 1600/1800 A
```

I need to get /1,800 or /200 or /1,800 or /1800

```
/(\d{1,3},)*\d+.?(\d{1,8}|)
```

this gives me 2 matches: ex. /1,800 and /01/2014

I have found pattern to exclude dates:

```
(?!(0?[1-9]|1[012])([-/.])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-/.])(19|20)\d\d)
```

but I don't know how to combine these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match only `/1,800` or `/200` or `/1,800` or `/1800`

```
\/(?:\d,\d{3}|\d{3,4})\b(?=[^\d]*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/9)

**OR**

```
\/(?:\d,\d{3}|\d{3,4})\b(?! \d)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/6)

`(?! \d)` This negative lookahead asserts that the characters which are following the numbers must not be `<space>` and a number. So this `/01/2014` match should be failed because it's followed by a space and a number.

Comment: Ty very very very much! Lost some hours with this.

Comment: Forgot one more situation :( It could be /50 for example. Can You please solve me for this one too? Thank You one more time! Maybe I found out: \/(?:\d,\d{3}|\d{2,4}(?!/))\b(?! \d)

Answer (score 2):

```
.*(\/\S+)
```

This simple regex should work for you.

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/11)